# How can I get the datatype of an attribute from a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am using Postgres in a Rails project and I have discovered that I need to change all of my `varchar` datatypes to `citext`. Rather than do this by hand, I want to just create a migration that loops through all of the models and their attributes and converts them as necessary.

Most of these models are empty, so it's not a matter of instantiating them. I need to find out if ActiveRecord "knows" what the datatype of its corresponding database column is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model.column_for_attribute('title').type
```

That might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Close but you get the prize for sending me in the right direction. I'm looking for the database datatype, and ```column_for_attribute.public_methods``` showed me there is a ```sql_type``` method which is just what I was looking for!