# How to generically get the value of a column from ActiveRecord columns array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a generic dumper / outputter of arbitrary table data, without having to individually specify each attribute.  So it would be OK to specify an object (table) but the attributes should take care of themselves (some one-time formatting by datatype may be required).

```
class ArbitraryRecordObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  # let ArbitraryRecordObject have an arbitrary list of attributes (mapping to db columns)
  # of type int, float, strings, dates and timestamps
end
```

I'm trying to do the following, without explicitly specifying attribute (ie column) names

```
for all instances of ArbitraryRecordObject (ie for each row in the arbitrary_record_objects table)
  for each column in each instance (ie each row)
    puts column.name + row.column.value.to_s # column.name works but don't know how to get the value
  end
end
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding finding the datatype, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16321677/877472), and the comment below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArbitraryRecordObject.all.each do |o|
  o.attributes.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key}: #{value}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
column_names = ArbitraryRecordObject.column_names

ArbitraryRecordObject.all.each do |row|
  column_names.each do |col_name|
    puts "#{col_name} #{row.send(col_name)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know send() could be used this way.